# What is the Regular Expression to allow only one hyphen(-) only between 2 letters or a letter and a number but not 2 numbers

Tags: regex

I was using the below pattern.

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9]+(-[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$/.
```

What i need is that it should not be allowing the hyphen between 2 numbers.
I know that we have to make modification with 0-9, where we can restrict user from entering them twice.

Comment: Not enough info. At the very least, you need to tell us the regex implementation/flavor you're using. Also, since this isn't a code-writing service, please show what you've tried so far and where you're stuck, so we can make specific suggestions. What exactly should be the output of your example cases? What about other cases like `r2-d2` or `abc123-123abc`?

Comment: Hi Tim,
Thanks for your time. I just want to restrict user from entering hyphen between numbers(123-123), but allowed if it only alphabets or alphanumeric(123-abc or abc-abc). Also please note that there can be only one hyphen to be allowed and that must appear in between, not at the beginning or end.

Comment: As usual, a lookahead is easiest here. `(?!.*\d-\d)` after `^` will do. And if there must be 1 or 0 hyphens, replace `*` at the end with `?`.

Comment: Does `^(?!.*\d-\d)[A-Za-z0-9]+(-[A-Za-z0-9]+)?$` work as expected?

Comment: (?!.*\d-\d), i tried this, it restricts the numbers, but it is also restricting the alphabets and alphanumeric, which should not be happenning.
Only numbers (123-123) should be restricted, alphabets or alphanumerc on hyphen's either side should be allowed and also only one hyphen should appear, that should be in between, not at beginning or at the end.

Comment: ^(?!.*\d-\d)[A-Za-z0-9]+(-[A-Za-z0-9]+)?$  is working perfectly. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi Chinmay, you can thank Wiktor by upvoting and accepting his answer (see the checkmark and up/downvote buttons next to it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `(?!.*[0-9]-[0-9])` lookahead after `^` will make sure there is no *digit-digit* pattern in the string. Also, if there must be 1 or 0 hyphens, replace `*` at the end with `?` (0 or more occurrences).

Use

```
^(?!.*[0-9]-[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9]+(-[A-Za-z0-9]+)?$
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gridqa/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*[0-9]-[0-9])` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, after any 0+ chars other than line break chars, there is a digit, hyphen, digit pattern
- `[A-Za-z0-9]+` - 1 or more ASCII alphanumeric chars
- `(-[A-Za-z0-9]+)?` - 1 or 0 sequences of:

  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `[A-Za-z0-9]+` - 1 or more ASCII alphanumeric chars
- `$` - end of string.